# C#. Построение диаграмм

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.
Есть приложение на c#, работающее с БД. Нужно визуализировать данные из БД в виде трехмерной(объемной) диаграммы. Существуют ли готовые библиотеки для работы с диаграммами, и если нет, то в какую сторону смотреть при разработке собственной? Спасибо.

Comment: Существуют, платных вообще немало, но и бесплатные есть. Вы лучше скажите, какого плана C#? Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET?

Comment: Windows Forms

Comment: Некоторые виды диаграмм в 3D умеет даже стандартный Chart из WinForms. 3D - понятие растяжимое, одному надо столбики объемные, другому - карту высот. И то, и то - диаграмма. При выборе компонента нужно отталкиваться от типа диаграммы, а уж сколько там D и насколько оно красиво, уже после того, как нашли несколько компонент, которые в принципе умеют рисовать нужную вам диаграмму.

Answer (score 2):

[RadChart for WinForms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/chart.aspx), по-моему для некомерческого использования беспалтен, поэтому можно скачать с офф. сайта, хотя я встречал и на торрентах.

- Имеет хорошую документацию
- Имеет КУЧУ годных бесплатных примеров

Answer (score 2):

ZedGraph, TeeChart - это опенсорс